# Spring boot 2.7.5 Springboot-JpaRepository & CrudRepository not saving the same Entity in the database

Tags: spring-boot, crud-repository, jparepository

I'm encountering a data integrity exception when attempting to save the same entity(even without changing its properties) after upgrading to Spring 2.7.5. Specifically, I'm seeing an error related to data duplication or primary key constraints.

This issue is not reproducible using spring boot 2.6.5.

How do I troubleshoot and resolve this issue?

Inputs:

- DB: mariaddb: 10.3
- Spring boot: 2.7.5
- dependecies:

  - org.springframework.boot:spring-boot
  - org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure
  - org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web
  - org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
  - org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client
  - org.flywaydb:flyway-core

While debbuging and enabling hibernate logs:

- Spring boot 2.7.5:
  `Hibernate: insert into customers (....`
- Spring boot 2.6.5:
  `Hibernate: update customers  set ....`

Code:

```
...
@Autowired
private CustomerRepository customerRepository;    
...
Optional<Customer> customer = customerRepository.findByEmail(email);
if (customer.isPresent()) {
   customerRepository.save(customer.get());
} else {
   Customer custom = new Customer();
   custom.setEmail(email);
   customerRepository.save(custom);          
}
...
```

StackTrace:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Duplicate entry 'dummy@gmail.com' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readErrorPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1674)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1536)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.getResult(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1499)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.executeQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:318)
    ... 80 common frames omitted
```

I tried to allign the versions of dependencies with spring boot 2.7.5.

Comment: Make sure you are executing this in a proper single transaction, and please properly use `Optional` use something like `ifPresentOrElse()` instead of a glorified `null` check.

Comment: Thank you, I agree, but it is just a demo code for test purposes, the real issue is while saving the entity.

Answer (score -1):

Use **save** method to **insert** the new data.

Use **update** method to **update** the data.

Use **merge** method when you want **to combine these two**. When data in not present insert it, when it is update it.

You are getting duplicated key exception because data is already present, and probably hibernate changed it's implementation between the version (check this in their docs if you want)

Comment: Thank you, 
I used both JpaRepository and  CrudRepository, which do not have merge & update methods.
the issue is only faced with springboot 2.7.5 or later even 3.0.x